# How to reference dynamically created form fields

Tags: javascript, html

My goal was to make a button which creates more fields for user inputs.
I have done that, but now need to reference the newly created fields.

At the moment I only know how to reference the original three fields because they have IDs, but the new ones don't.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="div1" >
Warm From:
<select id="hour_on_1">
    <option value = "0" ></option>
    <option value = "1" >1</option>
    <option value = "2" >2</option>
    <option value = "3" >3</option>
    <option value = "4" >4</option>

</select>
:
<select id="minute_on_1">
    <option value = "" ></option>
    <option value = "0" >00</option>
    <option value = "15" >15</option>
    <option value = "30" >30</option>
    <option value = "45" >45</option>
</select>

<select id="on_am_pm_1">
    <option value = "" ></option>
    <option value = "0" >am</option>
    <option value = "12" >pm</option>
</select>

&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Until:
<select id="off_hour_1">
    <option value = "" ></option>
    <option value = "1" >1</option>
    <option value = "2" >2</option>
    <option value = "3" >3</option>
    <option value = "4" >4</option>

</select>
:
<select id="off_minute_1">
    <option value = "" ></option>
    <option value = "0" >00</option>
    <option value = "15" >15</option>
    <option value = "30" >30</option>
    <option value = "45" >45</option>
</select>

<select id="off_am_pm_1">
    <option value = "" ></option>
    <option value = "0" >am</option>
    <option value = "12" >pm</option>
</select>

<br/>
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="add_item()">Add Another Period</button>
</body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">
function add_item(){
document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML += document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML
}
</script>
```

I need to be able to reference the value in any of the fields.

Currently I can only go something like:

> hour_on_1_value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("hour_on_1").value.trim())

To find the value in the top left field.

Would like to be able to do something like that but for any field

I would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Comment: i answered.... however do you want something more versatile(since i used a global var)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elementArr=[]
function add_item(){
  var x=document.createElement('div')
  var innerStuff=document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML
  var choiceLocation=document.getElementById('div2')
  x.innerHTML=innerStuff
  choiceLocation.appendChild(x)
  console.log(x) //just for you to see what is stored
  elementArr.push(x) //this is where the element is stored
  //each line has a different thing that you can manipulate to your suiting(cuz i cud've made it way shorter)
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="div1" >
Warm From:
<select id="hour_on_1">
    <option value = "0" ></option>
    <option value = "1" >1</option>
    <option value = "2" >2</option>
    <option value = "3" >3</option>
    <option value = "4" >4</option>

</select>
:
<select id="minute_on_1">
    <option value = "" ></option>
    <option value = "0" >00</option>
    <option value = "15" >15</option>
    <option value = "30" >30</option>
    <option value = "45" >45</option>
</select>

<select id="on_am_pm_1">
    <option value = "" ></option>
    <option value = "0" >am</option>
    <option value = "12" >pm</option>
</select>

&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Until:
<select id="off_hour_1">
    <option value = "" ></option>
    <option value = "1" >1</option>
    <option value = "2" >2</option>
    <option value = "3" >3</option>
    <option value = "4" >4</option>

</select>
:
<select id="off_minute_1">
    <option value = "" ></option>
    <option value = "0" >00</option>
    <option value = "15" >15</option>
    <option value = "30" >30</option>
    <option value = "45" >45</option>
</select>

<select id="off_am_pm_1">
    <option value = "" ></option>
    <option value = "0" >am</option>
    <option value = "12" >pm</option>
</select>

<br/>
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="add_item()">Add Another Period</button>
</body>
```